# Galactic Filaments and their connection to Galaxy centre

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, supermassive-black-hole

If alliptical galaxies seem to a line with their associated galactic filament and that orientation is related to connections between the mass of said galaxy and the dominating central object, which evolves that orientation. Is there a relation between these filaments and the supermassive central object as a start or destination point?

Comment: This reminds me of a Vernor Vinge novel.